# Alternatives of the word "legislate"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an essay about racial discrimination, and I came across this:

> "Laws have been ___ on racial discrimination..."

What verb should I use here? Set? Made? Also, I don't mean enforcing the law. I mean setting it.

Comment: See [promulgate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promulgate) definition 2b

Answer (score 2):

When something is legislated it's usually made into an "act"/"statute". Even if it isn't, "enact" is a fitting word I think.

> enact
>  vb (tr)
>   1. to make into an act or statute
>   2. (Law) to establish by law; ordain or decree
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/enact)
>
> enact
>  VERB
>  make (a bill or other proposal) law.
>   "legislation was enacted to attract international companies"
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enact)

Using your example sentence:

> "Laws have been enacted on racial discrimination..."

Comment: Sorry but I mean the creation of the law, not the enaction. Thanks still!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I'm not understanding what you mean. If you're talking about statute law (not common law), a law is created only when enacted. The proposal is usually drafted as a bill and created as law when enacted. I added a definition from Oxford Living Dictionaries. Edit: Sorry, I see that you've chosen promulgate already.

Comment: +1 I think this is the right choice in general. Although *promulgate* may be what was desired specifically, it's not a word most people would use or even know; *enact* is more commonly understood. Not to mention it's the word that lawmakers actually use. (Also, *promulgate* doesn't mean to create, it only means to announce . . .)